# Grails Spock - throwing an exception from a service UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, exception, spock

In runtime this code works:

```
// Service class
class UserService {
    ApiClient api

    User create(User user) throws EmailTakenException, UsernameTakenException {
        User savedUser 

        try {
            savedUser = api.users.create user
            setEnabled savedUser.id, true
            return savedUser
        } 
        catch(ApiException ex) {
            switch(ex.subStatus) {
                case SubStatus.USERS_EMAIL_TAKEN:
                    throw new EmailTakenException()
                    break
                case SubStatus.USERS_USERNAME_TAKEN:
                    throw new UsernameTakenException()
                    break
            }
        }                   
    }   
}
```

called from a controller:

```
// Controller class, an action
def create(CreateCommand cmd) { 
    if(request.get) {
        render view: 'create'
        return
    }

    if(!cmd.validate()) {
        flash.model = cmd
        redirect action: 'create' 
        return
    }

    def user = new User()
    bindData user, params

    try {           
        userService.create user

        flash.success = 'ui.save.success'       
    }
    catch(EmailTakenException ex) {
        flash.model = cmd
        flash.error = 'ui.email.taken'
    }
    catch(UsernameTakenException ex) {
        flash.model = cmd
        flash.error = 'ui.username.taken'
    }       

    redirect action: 'create'       
}
```

The "User", "SubStatus", and "ApiException" class comes from a jar library dependency. The ApiClient throws an ApiException when something goes wrong.

In runtime this code works perfectly, but when I write a Spec for this, it throws an UndeclaredThrowableException. Here's the Spock Specification:

```
ApiClient api
UsersApi apiUsers

void setup() {
    api = Mock()
    apiUsers = Mock()
    api.users >> apiUsers

    service.api = api
}

def "create: it should be able to throw an exception when email is already taken"() {
    setup:
    def user = new User(email: 'foo@cod.com', username: 'foo', name: 'Bar Foo')
    def exception = Mock(ApiException)
    exception.subStatus >> SubStatus.USERS_EMAIL_TAKEN

    when:
    service.create user

    then:
    thrown(EmailTakenException) // GrailsException is runtime
    1 * apiUsers.create(_ as User) >> { throw new ApiException(400, SubStatus.USERS_EMAIL_TAKEN, null) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could rewrite your test using the @FailsWith annotation?
http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics#Extensions

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work as well. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Which version of Spock are you using? and Grails? Normally you have to infer a type to your Mocks. I would not mock the exception either, you can create one directly, and it doesn't seem like you are using it anyway, are you?